# grunt-cssmin banner not working

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

Im using `gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin` to minify & concat my css files, I wanted to add simple banner on my output css file, but its not working

```
  cssmin : {    
     distribute : {
       options: {
          banner: 'MY BANNER '
       },

       files: {
         'style.css' : ['src/css/empty.css']
       }
     }
  },
```

and output is `body{background-color:#ff0}....` 
But expected output `MY BANNER body{background-color:#ff0}`

Comment: The [github page](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) says that "Remove banner option" was in the release notes for v0.11.0.